# NSPageController, deactivate swipe gesture

Tags: macos, swipe, gesture

I'm currently using a NSPageController to navigate between a Master and a Detail View in my OSX Application. I'm basically using it only to support transition animations, since there is no NavigationController on OSX.

However, the default NSPageController is listening on swipe gestures from my magic mouse and trackpad and changes the displayed view on a horizontal swipe. (like going back / forward in your browser). I would like to deactivate this behavior but overriding and intercepting any gesture method in a NSPageController subclass had no effect so far.

It seems like a NSScrollView / NSTableView does absorb these touches since doing a horizontal swipe gesture above any of my TableViews won't result in a view transition. (It only absorbs them for my magic mouse, doing a swipe gesture on my trackpad still results in switching views)

Target OS: Mac OSX 10.9 +

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make a subclass of NSPageController and overwrite

```
- (void)scrollWheel:(NSEvent *)theEvent
```

This should help.

Comment: Marc - is it possible expand this answer? How would you still allow vertical scrolling, for example?

Comment: NSPageController don't offer any functionality for vertical scrolling. If you are using a NSScrollView (e.g. with NSTableView) vertical scrolling should work as expected. I am only using it as explained but of course you could analyse the NSEvent deltaY or store the y value to compare and call [super scrollWheel:...] if needed.